# how to use feature hashing correctly in python

Tags: python, hash, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have many arrays of same dimension,such as

```
x = np.array([3,2,0,4,5,2,1...]) #the dimension of the vectors is above 50000 
y = np.array([1,3,4,2,4,1,4...])
```

What I want to do is to use **Feature Hashing** to reduce the dimensionality of these vectors(although there will be collisions).Then lower dimension vectors can be employed in classifiers.

What I have tried is

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
hasher = FeatureHasher()
hash_vector = hasher.transform(x)
```

However, it seems that `FeatureHasher` cannot be used directly and it says`AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'items'`

Therefore, in order to do feature hashing smoothly, what should I do next? 
Can anyone let me know if I am missing something? Or if there is another way to do feature hashing more effectively?

Answer (score 1):

The argument to the `transform` method must be an **iterable** of samples, not a single sample -- see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html .

But, there are more issues with your code: you're not passing `input_type` to build the hasher, so it's defaulting to `dict` -- "dictionaries over (feature_name, value)" (whence the need for `items`:-).

And anyway, no input type can make a hasher accepting "unnamed" features which you seem to want to pass to `transform` ... that's just not how feature hashing works.

You might consider different approaches to dimensionality reduction, such as http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/scikit-learn/#dimension-reduction-with-principal-component-analysis ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean if I want to use feature hashing, I must pass feature name to `transform` method, right? So is the feature name necessary?

Comment: Yes, that's what gets hashed in feature hashing -- no feature name, no feature hashing!  See more details at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing

Comment: Hi,teacher,thank you very much for your kind answer. I have another question. In `scikit`,it says feature hashing can be used in text classification. But if we use feature hashing to reduce the dimension of the training vector, it will worsen the accuracy, right? I really need your help.

Comment: @wanglan8498, in theory it might, but in practice with natural-language text the saving in space and time make it work well -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing and the links at the end of that article, esp. Ganchev and Dredze's.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. After reading the links you mentioned, now I see feature hashing is an effective method to save memory space, though it will reduce a little accuracy. By the way, if I want to focus on improving the accuracy of text classification,what kind of tricks can I use? Could you give me some ideas? I need your help.